# Substituting values in NSPredicate format

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I've been trying to figure out the different format for substituting in NSPredicate.  I'm aware "%@" is string, but what if we are looking for values like Double, Float,CGFloat, etc.  I did see "%i", I'm assuming its a substitute for integer but am not completely sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [official docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html), you can use `printf` format specifiers for other value types (but by the rest of the text I assume in most cases you will be good with `%@`):

> The format string supports printf-style format specifiers such as %x (see [Formatting String Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000943)). Two important format specifiers are %@ and %K.
>
> %@ is a var arg substitution for an object value—often a string, number, or date.
>
> %K is a var arg substitution for a key path.